Zero matrix for linearized system
I am given the following system, which I have to linearize such that I can describe the local phase portrait.
$x' = x^2, y'=y^2$.
The origin is the only equilibrium.
If I compute the Jacobian of this system, I get $
\begin{pmatrix}
2x & 0 \\
0 & 2y
\end{pmatrix}
$. Evaluated at $(0,0)$, I get the $0$ matrix. What I want to ask is, what does that tell me about the non-linear/linearized system? I looked in the textbook I got this probem from and I believe they do not address it. Any feedback is appreciated!

It tells you nothing.

@Artem Perfect.
